# Telethon which send message in group and wait for the output

Tags: python, telethon

I am creating a function in which, it send message to any group (like: /price) and wait for the reply. I am having a lot of problems. Here is the code:

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats = 'ChatId'))
        async def my_event_handler(event):
            nonlocal text_found
            text_found = event.raw_text
            await client.disconnect()
        await client(functions.messages.StartBotRequest(bot = '@Bot', peer = '@myHandle', start_param = '/price'))
        await client.run_until_disconnected()

    return text_found
```

It is not working and it is sending /start to the bot which i have to change into any message

I want that this file should be completed.

Answer (score 0):

[`StartBotRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/start_bot.html) always sends `/start` to the bot. `param` is similar to an URL query parameter (as in, `?start=param`), so some characters are probably invalid.

Your current code is similar to:

```py
await client.send_message('@Bot', '/start /price')
```

But you should instead use `client.send_message` directly with just `/price` and not `/start`:

```py
await client.send_message('@Bot', '/price')
```